# Referencing a Parent's ResourceDictionary in a UserControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, resourcedictionary

I have a library of WPF UserControls, and a ResourceDictionary that is shared within the library.

All the UserControls in this library appear only within a single 'shell' parent control, which is really just a container for a collection of smaller controls.  I'm able to access the ResourceDictionary from my shell control as expected when I add the following XAML

```
<Control.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResources.xaml" />
</Control.Resources>
```

However I can't access the ResourceDictionary from child controls that sit inside the 'shell' control.

I was under the impression that WPF should check locally for resources, and then traverse upwards until appropriate resources are found?

Instead I'm getting

```
Cannot find resource named '{BoolInverterConverter}'. 
Resource names are case sensitive.  Error at    
    object 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' in markup file...
```

Obviously I can (and am) referencing the ResourceDictionary in my child controls; but each and every control now needs to reference this dictionary and I believed that this was not necessary.

Any ideas, am I doing something strange or is my expectation of behaviour incorrect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's going on is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178.aspx), though the documentation's a little opaque.  If you add a `ResourceDictionary` to an element's`Resources` property without specifying a key, WPF expects that you're merging in resource dictionaries, and it populates the dictionary with the contents of the dictionaries in its `MergedDictionaries` property.  It ignores the actual contents of the `ResourceDictionary` with no key.

So what you want to do is this:

```
<Control.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
         <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResources.xaml"/>
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
   </ResourceDictionary>
</Control.Resources>
```

**Edit:**

A working example:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MergedDictionariesDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:MergedDictionariesDemo="clr-namespace:MergedDictionariesDemo" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <MergedDictionariesDemo:UserControl1 />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Dictionary1.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="UCBrush"
                     Color="Bisque" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

UserControl1.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MergedDictionariesDemo.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Border Margin="10" BorderBrush="Navy" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="10">
        <TextBlock Margin="10"
                   Background="{DynamicResource UCBrush}">
            The background of this is set by the resource UCBrush.
        </TextBlock>

    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; unfortunately this gives the same `Cannot find resource...` result as my original XAML.  I'm experimenting with using Keys but not finding any success.  Which part of the documentation link describes what is going on - I read it and while it's relevant to ResourceDictionaries I didn't see anything particular to whether or not Resources are available in a hierarchy of controls.

Comment: It's in the paragraph after the introduction, the one that begins "Note that the ResourceDictionary does not have an x:Key directive..."  Are you trying to retrieve the resource using the `StaticResource` markup extension?  Because that won't work.  `DynamicResource` will.

Comment: Robert - I was looking at your solution - even though using DynamicResource works - the compiler throws a compile time error saying Resource - the resource xxx cannot be resolved. Same can be replicated by your code above too. Any thoughts?